Spring Authorization Server OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant not working from Postman
I have used the default sample authorization server from the GitHub : default-authorizationserver
When I used Postman to start an authorization_code flow, I see the login page first and then when I enter the password, it always fails. I want to use the Spring Authorization Server to act as a OAuth2 provider as well just like Google / Keycloak. When I tried this with google, it worked seamlessly from Postman.
Here are some context.
Postman Starts the Authorization Code flow:

A Login Screen is displayed by the Spring Authorization Server.

The Error Page we see after a successful login:

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Wny do you call /oauth/authorize instead of /oauth2/authorize ?
